# Angular 2 & Ionic 2 http.put function wont send data

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am getting multiple json strings from an api like this:

```
{"id":"1","name":"test1","color":"red"}
{"id":"2","name":"test2","color":"green"}
```

And I loop them in an ion-item.
When clicked upon they toggle the colors between red and green, but the data is only temporary in the app itself, it's not being sent to the api.

```
PostData(data) {
    if (!data) return;
    var url = 'http://website.tld/page/' + data.id;
    if (data.color == 'green') {data.color = 'red'}
    else {data.color = 'green'};
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    urlSearchParams.append('name', data.name);
    urlSearchParams.append('color', data.color);
    let body = urlSearchParams.toString()
    return this.http.put(url, body, options)
    .map(res => res.json());
}
```

I have been successfull in changing the data by sending a PUT request with chome's postman app.

I append the clicked id behind the url, so the api knows which id needs to be changed.
I am using 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' and in the body I got 2 rows: name and color with a value next to them.

Comment: If you never subscribe to the Observable returned by PostData(), the request will never be sent.

Comment: How should I do this? Because I can't find it in any tutorial.

Comment: By calling subscribe() on the observable. It's covered by every rxjs tutorial: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#subscribing-to-observables

Comment: If I use the same subscribe as my working http.get function, I get this error: Return type of public method from exported class has or is using name 'Subscription' from external module "/path/to/rxjs/Subscription" but cannot be named... I am using: import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';